# Convert each slide to PNG with LibreOffice Impress in terminal with excel graph

Tags: libreoffice

I need to convert each slide in a powerpoint presentation to a PNG with the command line. I have tried to convert it to a PDF then to individual PNGs but the images haven't exported properly. These images are graphs originally from Microsoft Excel. If I export it as a PNG from within LibreOffice the graph exports properly, but not if I convert it to a PDF first using unoconv or the export tool in LibreOffice Impress. Here is a couple of examples, in impress: 
[image: In Impress]
As you can see the image works. But when this is exported to PDF it looks like: 
[image: Exported PDF]

So whats going wrong? As if its directly exported to PNG in libreoffice it looks exactly as is in the presentation. Also if I convert it to the LibreOffice file format this also happens.

Answer (score 2):

Change the PDF version to PDF/A-1a, with unoconv it can be done like so:

```
unoconv -f pdf -e SelectPdfVersion=1 somePresentation.ppt
```

Comment: It would be much visible and easy to find, if you set it a as accepted answer.